# Haskell Declare and Use "Set" Data Structure

Tags: haskell

I am trying to declare a custom "Set" datatype in Haskell that can hold elements so I have tried the following declaration:

```
data Set e = Set [e]
```

How can I declare a value of this type?

Comment: A tip: Because your `Set e` type has only one value constructor with only one field, you may want to use a `newtype` instead of a `data` declaration (simply substitute `newtype` for `data`); the resulting type will be equivalent, but will involve less overhead than it would with `data`.

Comment: Minor terminology note: in functional programming we rarely say things like "an instance of this data structure", but simply "a value of this type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a value of this type, you need to pass a list to the constructor `Set`:

```
> data Set e = Set [e]
> let myset :: Set Int; myset = Set [1, 2, 3]
```

To use it, you can pattern match on the constructor just like any other data type

```
> let len :: Set e -> Int; len (Set es) = length es
> len myset
3
```

If you are not in `ghci`, you don't need the `let`s.

```
myset :: Set Int
myset = Set [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect except I had to omit the "let"s for it to work :P

Comment: @gravysam The `>` was there to indicate that this was being entered into a GHCi session, a convention I see a lot here on SO.  If you were to put this in a `.hs` file and compile it you would indeed need to remove the `let`s.